# Strange pronunciation of 'assume'

Tags: pronunciation, dialect, connected-speech, assimilation-linguistics

Today I heard in two (totally unrelated) videos the same unexpected pronunciation of the word 'assume' by native speakers. Googling came up with /əˈsjuːm/ both for English and American pronunciation (and that's also what I had expected. However, what I heard in those videos clearly was something like "a-shoom". Is that a specific dialect?

Comment: Link to videos please

Comment: "**Yod coalescence** ‎(uncountable) (phonology): A process in English phonology whereby the clusters [dj], [tj], [sj], and [zj] become [dʒ], [tʃ], [ʃ], and [ʒ], respectively, through mutual assimilation." ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/yod_coalescence)). In your case, the cluster [sj] becomes [ʃ].

Comment: Your average American English speaker does *not* pronounce the word as either /əˈsjuːm/ or /əˈ ʃuːm/... that is some kind of British English pronunciation.

Comment: @Peter https://youtu.be/5XzLyM5kzgg?t=83
She does the same thing with other words. She is Australian, living in the US.

Comment: @Yay, this could have been an answer.

Comment: I have never ever heard a-shoom, only. ah-sue-oum

Answer (score 4):

As described in [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553135/365490), the pronunciation of *assume* in most British and Australian accents is /əˈsjuːm/ with the /s/ followed by a yod ('y' as in *you*). There's a tendency to merge an /s/ with the following /j/ ('y') to /ʃ/ ('sh' sound), so most people merge them to /ʃ/: **[əˈʃuːm]** (*a-shoom*). [[Assimilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology))]

By contrast, in most North American accents, the cluster /sj-/ has been simplified to /s-/, so they might pronounce it [əˈsuːm] (*a-soom*).

Another example is *bless you* pronounced *bleshoo* in fast speech.

And according to [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553169/365490), **[əˈsjuːm]** is the normal pronunciation of 'assume' in British English but it's possible though that some people might pronounce it **[əˈʃuːm]** in rapid speech and it isn't strange at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much incorrect as it is dialectal or personal (in the sense of how one pronounces things). I for one pronounce it as *a-shyoom*. I think it's a more British/Australian pronunciation.