# Why does "don't be" sometimes sound like "dombe"?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonology, connected-speech, assimilation-linguistics

Why does "don't be" sometimes become "DOMBE"? There is no M in the spelling then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

Some people pronounce *Don't be* as *dombe* because the *t* is sometimes deleted and the *n* is assimilated to an *m* in anticipation of the following *b*.

### Explanation

In *Don't be*, the /t/ is flanked by two consonants (/n/ and /b/) and in normal or casual speech, some people tend to drop some consonants (such as /t/ and /d/) when they come between two other consonants. The process of deletion is called **[elision](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/254188/106592)**. So when pronouncing *don't be* in casual speech, the /t/ is sometimes elided:

- Don't be [ˈdəʊntbiː] → don be [ˈdəʊnbiː]

Another process involved here is **[assimilation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248446/106592)** which makes nearby sounds similar. Adjacent sounds often influence each other so they become more similar (assimilated). For instance, the *n* in *ten pies* is likely to be pronounced /m/ in anticipation of the following bilabial stop—/p/.

After the elision of the /t/, we're left with:

- don be [ˈdəʊ**nb**iː]

The nasal /n/ in *don be* is likely to assimilate to a /m/ in

- don be [ˈdəʊ**nb**iː] → dombe [ˈdəʊ**mb**iː]

That's why some people pronounce it *dombe*.

Other examples of assimilation include:

- han**d**some → pronounced *hansom*
- *mi**ssio**n*, *vi**sio**n*, *trea**su**re* etc
- *assume* pronounced *[ashoom](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/267289/106592)*
- *handbag* pronounced *hambag* etc.

Comment: The elision of /t/ or /d/ when flanked by consonants requires that the preceding consonant matches in terms of voicing. This isn't the case in *don't be* where the preceding consonant is a voiced /n/. So you know for future posts, /t/ is freely elided in negative contractions. The relative likelihood is glottal stop, very likely; elision quite likely; [t] relatively unlikely.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: *The elision of /t/ or /d/ when flanked by consonants requires that the preceding consonant matches in terms of voicing* /// I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: That’s why you can’t drop the /t/ in *built this*. (Note as well that consonants in codas **don’t** have to match in voicing! That’s only true of obstruents)