# Pronunciation of [bunch'ed' together]: "ch+ed+t" cluster

Tags: pronunciation, consonants, consonant-clusters

The sheep "bunch**ed** together" as soon as they saw the dog.

VERY HARD to pronounce [~**ed t**~] together

"~ed" here is like "t" or "d"?

There are many [ch+ed] words. How should I pronounce them?

Are there any good rules for English learners to bear in mind?

For me "bunched together" sounds like just "bunch two gether"

Comment: If you type in "bunched pronounce" on google, we will be offered a built-in tool that pronounces words for you... it's a t at the end

Comment: You can usually omit the /t/ and /d/ when they're flanked by other consonants. *Handbag* is actually [ˈhæ**ndb**æɡ], but you'll hear some native speakers pronounce it [ˈhæ**mb**æɡ]; they omit the /d/ and assimilate the /n/ to /m/ in anticipation of the following /b/. So if you find such clusters difficult to pronounce, omit one of the consonants. See ["don't be" pronounced "dombe"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270790/106592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English consonant clusters can be difficult-to-pronounce at times,...

The *-ed* is pronounced /t/ in this case. I've expounded on the pronunciations of the *-ed* endings in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268682/106592)

Now, there are four consonants in a row in **bu[nt͡ʃt.t]ogether**, including the problematic /t͡ʃ/. The simple trick is to omit the *-ed*:

> #### bu[nt͡ʃ.t]ogether

That's how most native speakers pronounce it. However, what it means will depend on the context.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read phonetics so I'm not exactly certain how that's intended to be pronounced. In my own dialect, Yorkshire, BrE, the first 't' would become a glottal stop, the second pronounced, to retain some small delineation between the two words.

Comment: @gonefishin'again.: bu[nt͡ʃ.t]ogether → BUNCH-TOGETHER. I told the OP to omit the sound given by the *-ed* ('t' in this case).